# How can I install Tensorflow in Canopy ( Windows Environment)?

Tags: python, pip, enthought, canopy

I see so many libraries in Enthought Canopy, but couldn't find TensorFlow by google to train the CNN. If it is not there, how could I use TensorFlow Framework in Canopy.

I really don't want to change the platform. Is there any way I can use pip installation to use it in my canopy?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to install tensorflow into Canopy following the instructions here (without using `sudo`): https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/get_started/os_setup.html#pip-installation

In a Canopy Terminal (accessible from the Tools menu) you can run:

**OSX**

`export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.9.0-py2-none-any.whl`

`pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL`

**Linux**

`export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.9.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl`

`pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL`

Comment: Thanks @J.Corson I am using Windows environment.

Comment: @meJayu Looks like getting it to work on Windows will require using Docker or maybe Windows 10 insiders preview with bash support. See http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlayingWithTensorFlowOnWindows.aspx and https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17